# Missing System DLLs in .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild

I have a .NET solution consisting of several projects – most of these are just simple C# libraries. One of them is an MVC web application.

All the references of every project is missing references. Here is an example:

[image]

I have de-selected all projects for build except this one (shown above) simple c# library project which has no dependencies on any other in the solution.

I've checked things like the .csproj file in Notepad but can't see anything unusual.

If I remove one of the references such as System.XML and then re-add it, it gets re-added but still with the missing warning icon! So the DLLs are in the .NET Framework directory as you'd expect.

I'm really quite stumped with this.

It's .NET framework 4.5, Windows 7, x64.

Comment: Does this happen in new projects if you add one of those dependencies?

Comment: You can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275619/how-to-add-references-and-nugets-in-visual-studio-project-template/37275813?noredirect=1#comment62079434_37275813) Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Several points to check to know why they seem to be missing:

- Paths
- Assemblies: Are they built for the same .NET version of your
  project (Portable, not portable, windows phone, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

For the query you asked, you can refer the below link

[How to add references and nugets in visual studio project template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275619/how-to-add-references-and-nugets-in-visual-studio-project-template/37275813?noredirect=1#comment62079434_37275813)

For the references, according to the image, it may refer to the GAC and not the local bin folder of the solution.

Remember, the best way is always to maintain the references in the Bin/Reference folder and then refer from it. Add them to the solution so that you may not loose them when you compress and move them to another system.

The following link will help you how to add the references

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Following below steps resolved the issue.

1. Ensure the .dll exists in the properties path
2. Still,if issue exist,then click on properties that fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the particular project/class library and ensure that there are no errors. There is a 50% chance that the .dll file couldn't be generated due to errors during compilation.